# How to remove this message from journal (etcdserver/api/etcdhttp: /health OK (status code 200))

Tags: logging, kubernetes, etcd

I started work with Kubernetes recently and I noticed something.

When I run: `$ journalctl -f | grep -i "/health OK"`

This message repeat every 10 secs:

> Jan 04 18:41:**03** localhost a8653068fac3[1273]: 2021-01-04 18:41:03.122577 I | etcdserver/api/etcdhttp: /health OK (status code 200)

> Jan 04 18:41:**13** localhost a8653068fac3[1273]: 2021-01-04 18:41:13.121855 I | etcdserver/api/etcdhttp: /health OK (status code 200)

I would like to know what Kubernetes application are generating this and how to remove this message.

Answer (score 0):

`journalctl` is your interface into a single machine's journal/logging. All service files insert data into the systemd journal.

In the command `$ journalctl -f | grep -i "/health OK"`

`-f` flag you have used gives  the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they are appended to the journal. Your grep part of command searches for a pattern with ignoring case distinctions in patterns and input data, so that characters that differ only in case match each other.

The Kubernetes  [API server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-apiserver)  provides API endpoints to indicate the current status of the API server.  Using "`/health OK"` in command you are checking the `health`/`livez`/`readyz` of services.

See: [health-checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/health-checks/).
Your logs come from [etcd pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/). They are useful because they inform about status of your etcd in cluster. You can redirect these logs to file: `./bin/etcd 2>log.txt`

Take a look: [journalctl](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/reading-the-system-log.html).

Comment: If my answer was useful, please consider to upvote it and accept to be more visible for community.

Comment: Already upvoted, but my account have less than 15 reputation points, so the visual feedback are disabled.